# Integral of $x e^{5x^2 + 2}$

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I've tried integrating by parts.  But it doesn't seem to work, my first attempt seems more promising, but I don't know where to go after line 3.  Pls help
[My working out is posted in this pitcure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bomDr.jpg)

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}e^{[f(x)]} = f'(x) \times e^{[f(x)]}.$

Answer (score 3):

You have:
$$I=\int xe^{5x^2+2}dx=e^2\int xe^{5x^2}dx$$
now if we let $u=5x^2\Rightarrow du=10x dx\therefore dx=\frac{du}{10x}$ now putting this back in we get:
$$I=\frac{e^2}{10}\int e^udu=\frac{e^2}{10}e^u+C=\frac{e^{5x^2+2}}{10}+C$$

Comment: got it, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

$$\int xe^{5x^2+2}dx = \frac1{10} \int e^{5x^2+2}10x\,dx = \frac1{10} \int e^{5x^2+2}d(5x^2+2) = \frac1{10} \int e^u\,du$$